# SqlDeveloper - Real Time SQL Monitor doesn't log statements even though I can see them in Sessions

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I'm trying to trace an application that is running on my machine.

In SQL Developer, I go into Real Time SQL Monitor and run the tool. I can see various queries being logged, but none from the application.

When I go into Monitor Sessions, I can see the application's connection and, just for luck, I can right-click on the row and Enable Session Trace. When I click on the row and look at the "Active SQL" tab in the lower pane, I can see statements flash up and disappear. This indicates to me that tracing *should* be working?

How can I get the statements to show up in the Real Time SQL Monitor so I can investigate them properly?

Answer (score 1):

Not all statements are captured and displayed by SQL Monitoring.

https://blogs.oracle.com/coretec/post/oracle-database-real-time-sql-monitoring-one-of-the-most-important-tools

> Statements that are not necessarily "long-running" are automatically
> listed if they fulfill the following properties. For a single
> statement execution, at least one of the following conditions must be
> met:
>
> - parallel execution
> - a resource consumption of at least 5 seconds I/O or CPU time
> - use of the special statement hint MONITOR ( e.g. select /*+ MONITOR */ ... from ...)